# getting local notification while the app is in background

Tags: ios, localnotification

while the app is in background didReceiveLocalNotification is not called.

So I try to get the notification from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 
 UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions  objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
//...
}
```

But My App is with Background Mode enable (using external accessory communication)
When click on the notification,  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not called.

Any other way to retrieve notification ?

Comment: When your app is in background local notification will come automatically, `didReceiveLocalNotification` is used when your app is in foreground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By checking [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) about notifications, it says:

> iOS Note: In iOS, you can determine whether an application is launched
> as a result of the user tapping the action button or whether the
> notification was delivered to the already-running application by
> examining the application state. In the delegate’s implementation of
> the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: or
> application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method, get the value of the
> applicationState property and evaluate it. If the value is
> UIApplicationStateInactive, the user tapped the action button; if the
> value is UIApplicationStateActive, the application was frontmost when
> it received the notification.

As far as I know, when your app is in background-running state, and there comes a local notification, you won't receive any method call, the notification will be displayed to user, but if  user tap the notification and thus reactive your app, you will receive `-didReceiveLocalNotification:` call.