# UILocalNotification in background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

I had implemented the code regarding `UILocalNotification` in my app and so far it is working very well for every case except one case.The problem i am facing is when the user receives local notification and the app is in background, then user open the app by pressing app icon,in this case i am not getting any method to provide me notification data.
All other cases i had managed in `DidReceiveLocalNotification` and `DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.
Please someone tell me the proper way to sort this problem out.

Comment: you are sure that notification is sent when app is in background ?

Answer (score 0):

please check this Link :

[getting local notification while the app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356064/getting-local-notification-while-the-app-is-in-background)